# capture event after user comes back to view controller from location settings

Tags: ios, swift

Trying to build a simple app where user will be prompted to allow location access. If user does not allow I am providing a button to go into settings and provide access.

Lets say if user gives the app permission to use location when in use and click on the default "Back to <>" button on the tap. In this case how do I capture the event and perform some action.

Trying this sample in swift

Comment: *"Back to App" default button from settings

Answer (score 2):

There is method in `CLLocationManagerDelegate` Protocol.

```
optional func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager!, didChangeAuthorizationStatus status: CLAuthorizationStatus)
```

> This method is called whenever the application’s ability to use
>   location services changes. Changes can occur because the user allowed
>   or denied the use of location services for your application or for the
>   system as a whole.

[More Details](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManagerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/CLLocationManagerDelegate/locationManager:didChangeAuthorizationStatus:)